# Application.Exit() not working when using form closing methods to minimise to tray

Tags: vb.net

I am using this code to minimise the form to the tray when the **X** button is pressed

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
    NotifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Application
    NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info
    NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Running In the Background"
    NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Application is running in the Background. Double click it to maximize the form"
    NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(50000)
    Me.Hide()
    ShowInTaskbar = True
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

I have a **Quit** button too which will actually exit the application, but I think it's using the code above to minimise the form instead.

```
Private Sub btn_Quit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Quit.Click
    Dim confirm As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wish to Exit the App?", "Exit Application?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If confirm = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I override the `FormClosing` sub when using the **Quit** button?

I tried using `End` but that didn't work either

Comment: Add a Boolean variable to the form, call it quitRequested.  Set it to True in the button event handler.  Now you know that you should not set e.Cancel to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the FormClosingEventArgs passed to Form_Closing handler. It will tell you whether someone tried to close the Form, or if the application is exiting. There are other reasons too which you can check out

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Select Case e.CloseReason
        Case CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall
            e.Cancel = False
        Case CloseReason.FormOwnerClosing
            NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
            NotifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Application
            NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info
            NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Running In the Background"
            NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Application is running in the Background. Double click it to maximize the form"
            NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(50000)
            Me.Hide()
            ShowInTaskbar = True
            e.Cancel = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: that seemed to close fully for both, so i changed it to this and it worked perfectly `If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall Then
            e.Cancel = False Else e.Cancel = True End If`